# How to get the previously related record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a Feed model that looks like this:

```
Feed (id, project_id, content)
```

Given a `Feed` object like so `(3031, 13, 'yada yo ya')`.

I want to find the Feed item, if any, that is before the feed object listed above. and it has to be for that `project_id`.

Something like, given `@feed.project_id`, find all `Feed` items for that `project_id`, and return the record previous to `@feed = Feed.find(3031)` if any.

Complicated right? Ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You could run a query of all feeds for that project prior to the current feed and just pull the last record:

```
@feed = Feed.find(3031)
@previous_feed = Feed.where("id < ? and project_id = ?", @feed.id, @feed.project_id).order("id").last
```

Comment: Thanks but that seems to return the same record every time for each feed item. Doesn't seem to take into account the current item?

Comment: I suggest you make sure you set the order too. `Feed.order("id DESC").where(*blah*).first`

Comment: @Matthew - good suggestion, updated my answer. (At least with Rails 3, you should be able to just sort by ID and call last, it'll basically reverse the sort and call first behind the scenes -- i.e., it won't return the whole result set, just one record)

Comment: You're right @dmarkow, the only time it would break is when there's a default scope. (I think `reverse_order` would respect that). But still I prefer being precise about order. Using `last` is not something I'd do.